# subset sum - finding the maximum sum strict lower than m with subset size k

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset, knapsack-problem

I'm struggling with the following problem: given an set of n items, find the maximum sum of the subset of size k that is strictly lower and as close as possible to a given number m.

I have solved the problem without the constraint that the subset has to be of size k and this is my code (nums is the array where I save my n numbers):

```
// clear the dp array
int dp[n+1][m+1];
for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < m+1; j++)
        dp[i][j] = 0;

for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
{
    for(int w = 1; w < m; w++)
    {
        if(nums[j-1] <= w) dp[j][w] = max(dp[j-1][w], nums[j-1] + dp[j-1][w - nums[j-1]]);
        else dp[j][w] = dp[j-1][w];
    }
}
cout << dp[n][m-1];
```

However, I'm not sure how to extend my code to give the answer with subsets of size k. I was thinking about having another dimension in the table that keeps track of the items added already but I'm not sure on how to implement this. I've already search this site but I didn't find a concrete answer that helps me to write the code.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120659/largest-sum-of-k-elements-not-larger-than-m#comment21280149_15120659

Comment: @ruakh No that's not intentional, I've edited it, thanks!

Comment: @UdoKlein that's exactly the problem I'm solving! :D I will try the optimized brute force, thanks for the link!

Comment: If you solve this problem, you can solve the [subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), so this problem is NP-complete